# csv.writer can't handle QUOTE_NONE and empty escapechar since python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.11

Since Python 3.11, the `CsvWriter` with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` raises an error when trying to generate data containing `quotechar` (`"`). It asks for an `escapechar` to be defined.

The CSV I need to generate does not require quotes around the field, nor does it require the `quotechar` to be escaped.

*The documentation explains that escapechar is required as of Python 3.11, but doesn't explain how to work around this new requirement.*

Example that works with python 3.10, but raises an error with python 3.11:

```py
import csv
output = StringIO()
csv_writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
csv_writer.writerow((1,"This is a \"Test\"",2))
print(output.getvalue()) # 1, "This is a test", 2
```

I've tried setting `escapechar=""` but the value must be a 1 character string.

Any idea why Python would change the behaviour of the csv writer? and how to have Python 3.11 continue to generate this kind of csv?

Comment: Incorrect, it works for me in Python 3.11.2

Comment: Same for me on 3.11.0

Comment: and works on Python 3.11.3 though you might try throwing on a `escapechar="\\"` and see if that helps your instance.

Comment: I do get the error if I run your code, but omit the `quotechar=None`.

Comment: Sorry I've done a try with quotechar which i didn't removed. And you are true I didn't notice it works with it, this is the solution ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with python 3.11 is to specify that there is no `quotechar` with `quotechar=None`

```py
import csv
output = StringIO()
csv_writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None)
csv_writer.writerow((1,"This is a \"Test\"",2))
print(output.getvalue()) # 1, "This is a test", 2
```